# Javascript Validate URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following code to validate URL in client side. My question is if there is a better way to do the same..**My question is not about the regex that i am using (just the overall way of writing)**

```
this.validators.myUrl = function(value) {
    if (!_.isUndefined(value) && !_.isNull(value)) {

    if ($.trim(value).length == 0) {
        return {
            isValid: true
        } 
    }   else {

        return /^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test($.trim(value)) == true ? {
            isValid: true
        } : {
            isValid: false,
            message: "Enter a valid URL"
        };
    }
    } else {
        if ($.trim(value).length == 0) {
        return {
            isValid: true
        }
    }
    }
};
```

Comment: `<input type="url" />` problem solved.

Comment: @testndtv; are those only image urls?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to use ready plugins/libraries?

You can have used [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and its [`url`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/) method.

All what you need is:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            url: true
        }
    }
});
```

where `myform` is id of your form.

Comment: @testndtv; you are already using JQuery "$.trim()", that is also a third party library

Comment: @testndtv why you can't use it? You are using `$.trim()` function, so why you can't add jquery validation plugin like you did with jQuery?